# How to search and replace a string in a file with cmd or PowerShell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I have a .txt file in which I want to replace the string `aaa` with `bbb`.

I have tried the following PowerShell code:

```
Get-Content c:\1.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "aaa", "bbb" } | Set-Content c:\1.txt
```

I get an error that `1.txt` is being used by another process. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
(get-content c:\1.txt) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "prod", "qa1"} | set-content c:\1.txt
```

The parentheses around `Get-Content` ensure that the Get operation is completed before the Set operation begins, without this the two functions would both try to access the file at the same time.