# How do i write a BATCH script that detects which OS it's running on? (dos or Windows CMDline)

Tags: boot, script, macros

I'm writing a script that:
1. Detects which OS it's running on, win10 or win8 (just these two options)
2. Does three *Find and Replace*-actions
3. starts up the program that belongs to it.
Below is an attempted CMD/DOS batch script:

```
01    set %versionOS%  to ver
           REM in the above line I want to fill a variable called
           REM %versionOS% with the output of the ver commmand

02    IF  %versionOS% = "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]"
           REM in the above line I check if variable
           REM %versionOS% equals "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]"

03    command to close an application.
           REM in the above line I want to close an application 
           REM  c:\path\WinCmd.exe this line could be the 1st line too, yes   

04   goto Win10
05        *commmands that change wincmd.ini to one that's suited for Win8
06        (I've figured this one out already)*
07    goto ProgStart
08    :Win10
09         *commmands that change wincmd.ini to one that's suited for Win10*
10   
11    :ProgStart
12     c:\path\WinCmd.exe
```

I'd like help with the first 3 lines. Thanks.

Comment: Approaching it from a different angle to remove the need for search/replace, you could simply create two versions of the INI file, call them WinCmd_8.ini and WinCmd_10.ini with the relevant differences. Then all you need is two similarly named BAT/CMD files with two instructions: Copy the version-specific INI to WinCmd.ini (overwrite it), then start/restart WinCmd.

Comment: @MikeFitzpatrick has a good point. The above will simplify the script enormously. But that said, SuperUser is not a "Please write me a script" kind of service, so your question is considered Off-Topic here. If you have an actual script, not in conceptual language, but in .cmd language, feel free to ask us why its not working and we'll help you out.

Comment: Expanding on @MikeFitzpatrick's comment, there are lots of ways to work out the operating system version number from DOS. See https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-windows-os-version-from-command/ for details.

Comment: @MikeFitzpatrick the INI is not static. So I can't simply overwrite it, because then all my history and other changes would be gone. I do things in Win8 that are relevant to, build upon things i do in Win10, and then I do things that continue again in Win8

Comment: @LPChip Please note that i DID NOT ask you to write me a script, I asked you HOW, which does include advise on which language, tools or apps would be appropiate to do this. Is it DOS, C++, a script language? Probably not Assembler or IBM's APL. Please remove your down vote, I now kind of feel like a female gamer.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic - it's too broad, opinion based and seeking recommendations on tools (although I'm not down voting as the question is well written and clear). Sorry, but felt it is better to give feedback than to not!

Comment: Stack Overflow has some good resources: [Search and replace using DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742686/search-and-replace-in-a-file-using-windows-batch-programming), as well as [getting the Windows version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212033/get-windows-version-in-a-batch-file). They should be at least something to get you started.

Comment: I suspect you can achieve what you want with Powershell. https://superuser.com/questions/1083142/how-to-detect-each-windows-os-is-used-with-powershell and https://superuser.com/questions/517760/how-to-search-and-replace-a-string-in-a-file-with-cmd-or-powershell/517762

Comment: @GwenKillerby I did not vote you down. I don't vote down questions unless the intent is spam.

Comment: @dAVE i'm open to suggestions to make the question less broad. Also what part is opinion based???? Baffled.

Comment: Gwen - You should not need to open the ini file to modify the content of the file to replace a string with another. Everything you request seems possible but you'll need to confirm where file path location wise the `WinCmd.ini` resides. I assume this is a TotalCommander file or something but I don't use or have installed but that shouldn't matter for it to work. Are you willing to use PowerShell within a batch file to complete this task or a 3rd party app with no install needed such as F.A.R.T or SED if you cannot use PowerShell logic within a batch to complete the task?

Comment: @GwenKillerby if you're after advice, the advice can be opinion based. You should use PHP for this, vs Powershell, vs VBscript etc...

Comment: I've now got the PS to do the changes to the wincmd.ini, but now I wanna make them conditional.
**How do I fill a variable with the output of the ver command?**. I hope @Dave ,  that's specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in selling houses the three most important things are **location, location, location**, it seems that in answering questions, the three most important things are **motivation, motivation and motivation**...apparently. Here's my solution, it works like a charm. Feel free to comment, everything is subject to improvement.. <3 <3 <3

```
taskkill /im TOTALCMD64.EXE
IF %USERDOMAIN% == GwenKillerby goto Win10
echo win8
    powershell -Command "(Get-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'D\:\\', 'QzQ' } | Set-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini"    
    powershell -Command "(Get-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'C\:\\', 'D:\' } | Set-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini"    
    powershell -Command "(Get-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'QzQ', 'C:\' } | Set-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini"    
    powershell -Command "(Get-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\\',  '\'   } | Set-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini"    
goto ProgStart
:Win10
echo win10
     powershell -Command "(Get-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'C\:\\', 'QzQ' } | Set-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini"
     powershell -Command "(Get-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'D\:\\', 'C:\' } | Set-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini"
     powershell -Command "(Get-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'QzQ', 'D:\' } | Set-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini"
     powershell -Command "(Get-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\\',  '\'   } | Set-Content f:\totalcmd852\wincmd.ini"
:ProgStart
    f:\totalcmd852\TOTALCMD64.EXE
```

(BTW: if anyone can tell me why in `'C\:\\', 'D:\'` 'C' **needs** two slashes while for 'D' one is enough, I'd be so happy.)
First, I tried to make it conditional upon Windows version via a tmpfile which is a more elegant and robust manner.

```
rem VER > tmpFile
rem set /p myvar= < tmpFile
rem del tmpFile
```

But I couldn't get it to work, so I used UserWhatever. Also, the output of **VER** in both Win10 and 8 are virtually identical: **Microsoft Windows [6.xxx]** versus  **Microsoft Windows [10.xxx]**, which means working with those creepy tokens, brrrr!
I'm open to any solution which has less lines or is less complex than. Or, you know, a full PS script/batfile ... ;) ;) ;)